# Use of unresolved identifier 'UIBezierPath'

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am building a project that is using a charting library I originally found when building android apps called MPAndroidCharts. It has been ported over to iOS/Swift and had been working great. I came across a weird problem though. Friday when I left work the project was working perfectly, I test the app at the end of each day and the beginning of each day, not sure why, it's just how I do it. So it was working Friday when I left work, I came in today opened up the project and tried to build it, now I am getting build failure saying "Use of unresolved identifier 'UIBezierPath' did you mean 'NSBezierPath'?" I have not updated anything on my system and nothing has changed in the code base, but now it won't build.

When I try to update it to NSBezierPath I get a bunch of other errors because it doesn't have the same arguments in the constructor and I am not 100% sure how to convert it over to NSBezierPath. My constructor is simple(ish)...

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: barRect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius))
let roundedPath = bezierPath.cgPath
```

When I update to NSBezierPath I get errors about UIRectCorner needing to be NSRectPointer, which doesn't have the ".allCorners" and then the constructor is all wrong and it doesn't build.

I am trying to make this not too general because I know that is bad, but I don't know how to fix it, or why it just magically became unresolved over the weekend without me updating xCode or my code base, or any associated libraries. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need it the link to the charting library is ... https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now I am getting build failure saying "Use of unresolved identifier 'UIBezierPath' did you mean 'NSBezierPath'?"

`UIBezierPath` is a UIKit class, and since UIKit is an iOS framework you can use `UIBezierPath` in iOS projects but not macOS projects. `NSBezierPath` is an AppKit class, and AppKit is a macOS framework, so you can use it on macOS but not iOS.

If Xcode is offering `NSBezierPath` as an alternative, then it sounds like you've somehow switched your target to build for macOS instead of iOS. Check that, and also check that your project links against UIKit.

> When I try to update it to NSBezierPath I get a bunch of other errors because it doesn't have the same arguments in the constructor and I am not 100% sure how to convert it over to NSBezierPath.

You shouldn't switch to `NSBeziierPath` unless you're porting your project to macOS. If that's what you're doing, then yes, you'll need to switch, and you'll need to read [the `NSBezierPath` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbezierpath) to figure out how to rewrite your code to use that API. Briefly, it looks like you should be able to use [`init(roundedRect:,xRadius:,yRadius:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbezierpath/1520638-init) with `cornerRadius` for the last two parameters.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't know exactly what happened. Nothing got changed in any of the settings or anything, xCode just messed up when it opened the project. I quit xCode and restarted it and it built just fine. Somehow xCode got confused when I opened it and it thought the project was for macOS and not iOS. That was weird.